# Saving Active Directory Configuration settings to a file

Tags: powershell, active-directory, domaincontroller

I'm using my machine to run a script on the Domain Controller server using `Enter-PSSession`. It all works except, I can't save the outputs from the script on my local machine.

I want to save the outputs from the script as objects in my local machine in a csv format (Not on the Domain Controller server).

What I'm trying to do is save results from running commands like `Get-ADDomainController` etc..

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for this …

> I can't save the outputs from the script on my local machine.

… sure you can. Just create a log file as part of your session and copy that file back to your workstation for review, or just use the *-Transcript cmdlets to that creates a file automatically that you can copy over. The transcript will record everything that happens in the sessions.

```
Get-Command -Name '*transcript*' | ft -a

CommandType Name             Version Source                   
----------- ----             ------- ------                   
Cmdlet      Start-Transcript 3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Host
Cmdlet      Stop-Transcript  3.0.0.0 Microsoft.PowerShell.Host


# get function / cmdlet details
(Get-Command -Name Start-Transcript).Parameters
Get-help -Name Start-Transcript -Full
Get-help -Name Start-Transcript -Online
Get-help -Name Start-Transcript -Examples
```

Or, don't use the interactive Enter-PSSession (explicit PowerShell Remoting) that puts you directly on the DC. Use a Implicit PSRemoting session, using New-PSSession and proxy the AD cmdlets to your machine for use.

```
$SessionAD = New-PSSession -ComputerName ''dc01.contoso.com
Invoke-Command $SessionAD -Command {Import-Module ActiveDirectory}
Import-PSSession $SessionAD -Module ActiveDirectory | Out-Null

$ADUSers = Get-ADuser -Filter *
$var = $ADUSers | Select-Object -Property Name, SamaccountName | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single 

$GroupsMember = Get-ADUser -Filter ('Name -eq "' + $var.Name + '"') -Property MemberOf |
                Select -ExpandProperty MemberOf |
                Get-ADGroup -Property MemberOf |
                Select Name

$GroupsMember
Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
```

Then you can run ADDS cmdlets as if they are actually on your machine and results are on your machine, or if you are on Window 8 or higher, just [download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7887) and [install](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28972) (Win 7 - 8) / [enable the RSAT tools](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2693643/remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-operating-systems) (Win 10) directly and use them.

[Remoting the Implicit Way](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/remoting-the-implicit-way/)

[PowerShell Implicit Remoting: Never Install a Module Again](https://www.itprotoday.com/powershell/powershell-implicit-remoting-never-install-module-again)

Also, take a look and [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-6) for running command locally or remotely.

Comment: No worries. Please ensure to mark this as your accepted answer for other who may be looking for the same results for similar use cases.